# Get Download Link with Metadata in Dropbox API

Tags: php, download, dropbox

I have very basic and quick question. I am using PHP Dropbox API class written by Ben Tadiar. I use `$object->metaData("/");` to get file list from dropbox. The data return does not include URL to download/preview of the file. So I have to call `$object->media()` method for each file to get the URL which results in **lot of delay** specially when file list is too long.

Is there anyway to get the download link along with filelist ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I could not find any way to get download URL along with file list. The work around would be to list all the files without calling `$object->media()` on each item. Instead, call this method to the file that user selected to download.
A simple quick function would be something like this:

```
function getDBDownloadUrl($Path){
    try{
        $mdb = new MyDropbox();
        $download = $mdb->media($Path);
        $download = $download['body'];
        return $download->url;
    }

    catch(Dropbox\Exception $e){
        return array("error"=>1, "message"=>"There was a problem accessing file download URL from dropbox");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling /metadata are you calling it with 'list' set to true? If so, can't you get the path from the contents array for the file you want and GET /files with that path? https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#metadata

Comment: Kevin, the path is like "/my-folder/sub-folder/somefile.txt" but the downloadURL is like "https://dl.dropbox.com/0/view/zvj04koo8fx2cly/..."
This is the direct URL to the file...